# SharePoint 2010 Web analytics show 0 data

Tags: sharepoint, web, analytics

we are having sharepoint analytics data problems. This has been working recently, and then all of a sudden when we look into our analytics report all we see is 0's for the past month. I have been looking for solutions to no success. Ive already followed this guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx and did all the steps but still get the same issue/no data.

Comment: Well... What's the issue?

Comment: web analytics does not show any data at all. thats the issue. number of page views reflect 0 on all days. which shouldnt be the case